# Purify blank cells on Excel

Tags: excel

first of all: I am using Excel 2007 with a .XLS file.

I have a column that contains some cells with values but other random cells are in "blank".
But when I do ISBLANK on this cells it returns me FALSE on all of them. So I assume they contain a value, and I want them really blank (only the cells I see without values).

I already tried replacing spaces with nothing, and nothing with nothing but still not working.

Thanks.

Comment: So you are trying to create a truly empty cell? Just hit the `DELETE` key when selected?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: What happens if you just click on the cell and click delete on your keyboard?

Comment: My guess is you have a non-display character in that field.

Comment: Yes, if I hit delete, it is true after. But there are more than 20000 random rows here... But if I try to select with F2, I cannot select anything to replace it. Thanks! I have no code, this is not VBA, only data.

Comment: It could be that there are other values in those cells, such as a carriage return and/or new line. It might be worth trying to select one such cell and hit delete/backspace and see if that does the trick. If it does you could copy the contents of another empty cell and use that in your find/replace.

Comment: look at a few using the formula `=Code(A1)` changing A1 to be a cell that is visually blank but returns false on isblank.. If you can identify the non-display character that way you can replace it like you are iwth the spaces.

Comment: already tried that, but it really doesn't have any selectionable or pasteable value.
=CODE() returns: #¡VALOR!   (spanish excel)

Comment: In a empty column use this `=Trim(Clean(A1))` and copy down.  Where A1 is the first cell in your column you are testing.  Then copy and paste the values back.

Comment: Dang.. `Clean` who new!  Thanks @scottcraner

Comment: This seems to work scott! ;) I'll do some checks here, thanks!

Comment: So... How do I "render" that formulas to values conservating the 'blank' as 'blank'? When I paste them as Values, that blanks are not blanks anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to cleanup and run:

```
Sub KleanUp()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = "" Then r.Clear
    Next r
End Sub
```